# How to remove characters from a field in Pig

Tags: apache-pig

**Data:**

> someId,+1 5552221234
>   someId2,+1 3331114321

I want to remove the +1 from the second field below

I first load the data
A= LOAD 'Data' USING PigStroage(,) as (Id:chararray, Phone:chararray)

Now i want to have the following Data

**Desired Output:**

> someId, 5552221234
>   someId2, 3331114321

How would i go about doing this.  I was using the following but it doesn't work:

mss_demographic_data3= FOREACH mss_demographic_data2 GENERATE *, REGEX_EXTRACT_ALL(Phone, '[0-9]{9}$') as newPhone;

Answer (score 0):

Use the substring function. (**easiest way**)

```
mss_demographic_data3= FOREACH mss_demographic_data2 GENERATE Id,SUBSTRING(Phone,3,12);
```

**NOTE-** You have this (substring function) only if you are using pig 0.8.0 or above. If you are using older version of pig, you may need to write an udf.